# Align the text with differing fontsizes in two adjacent div blocks

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-size

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/eNzjZ/81/

```
<style>
.bigLabel {    
   font-size: 128px;    
}

.smallLabel {    
   font-size: 64px;    
}

</style>
<div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 102px; height: 170px; z-index: 216614; overflow: visible; cursor: default;">
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="102px" height="170px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="bigLabel" style="padding:0px;background-color:yellow;" align="bottom" valign="bottom">T32</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 170px; z-index: 216632; overflow: visible; cursor: default;">
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="400px" height="170px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="smallLabel" style="padding:0px;background-color:orange;" align="bottom" valign="bottom">T0.00 0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the bottoms of the text in the two blocks do not line up.
The bigger font is higher than the smaller one.

Is it possible, changing only the css or style attributes to get these two pieces of text to align to the bottom?

Comment: Why you made it so complex? Do you need this table and all? Or just the output as shown?

Comment: What Alias said.. Why the table etc etc? Seems massively unnecessary for what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: I do not have control over the html, it is rendered by a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add line height to the text having bigger font size.

```
<td class="bigLabel" style="padding:0px;background-color:yellow; line-height: 115px;" align="bottom" valign="bottom">T32</td>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNzjZ/82/)

Comment: This works nicely, although what is the relationship between line-height and the font-size? the 115 line-height seems to have been arbitrarily chosen? Changing font-sizes makes everything skewed again. Is there no solution that works for all font-sizes?

Comment: It is better explained at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/